# Number of solutions to an equation $6\ln(x^2+1)-e^x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I need to determine how many solutions the equation $6\ln(x^2+1)-e^x = 0$ has. I wanted to find monotonic intervals of this function and check function's values at local extrema so I calculate determinant of the function, which is $\dfrac{12x}{x^2+1} - e^x$, but I have no idea how to solve any of these equations. Can you help me?

Comment: Here's what wolframalpha has to say about the matter, at least: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++6+ln%28x%5E2%2B1%29%E2%88%92e%5Ex%3D%3D0

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to $\ln(x^2+1)^6-\ln(e^{(e^x)})=0$ which is equivalent to $\ln\left(\frac{(x^2+1)^6}{e^{(e^x)}}\right)=0$.  So you need $(x^2+1)^6 = e^{(e^x)}$.  Graphing them it seems there must be three solutions, one with $x<0$, one with $0<x<1$ and one with $x>1$.

Comment: As $f(-\infty)>0,f(0)=-1<0,f(1)=6\ln2-e>0,f(\infty)<0$, there are at least three roots.

Comment: @Yves Yes, but in this situation I should prove that there aren't any more roots in these intervals

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Also, it is easy to show that there is one and only one negative root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\le0,~$ $~6\ln(x^2+1)$ is strictly decreasing, and $e^x$ is strictly increasing, so, if they ever meet, they can only meet once. And meet they must, since the former decreases from $\infty$ to $0$, while the latter increases from $0$ to $1$, so their two paths inadvertently cross.

---

For $x\in(0,1)$, approximate both functions with their Taylor series, and solve the corresponding quadratic equation. Use $\ln(1+t)\simeq t$ and $e^u\simeq1+u$.

---

For $x\ge1$, one function is strictly convex, while the other is strictly concave, so they can meet no more than twice. But in order for this to happen, the convex function must start at a value superior to that of the concave one, which isn't the case here, since $6\ln2>e^1$. So they can only meet at most once.

---

Thus we have shown that there are no more than three roots at the *most*. Now remember Yves Daoust's comment, which says that there are at *least* three roots, and draw the conclusion.

Comment: I'm unconvinced that what you say about the $x\in (0,1)$ case resolves that case.  By what rationale do we declare that the number of solutions in that interval is limited by those of a first order approximation?